# Selenium Python - click on a link inside <li > <a herf

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, automation

It is a very unique situation that I can't get it to work out. after logging into the website I want my code go and click on one of the times in the left side menu bar which has below element:

```
            <hr>
            <span class="hide-on-toggle" style="color: #225515;margin-left:10px;">GO</span>
            <br>
            <li class="hide-on-toggle jizzzHidden">
                <a href="/JIZZZ" target="_blank">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i><img src="/resource/153270/images/logo.png">
                    </i>
                  </span>JIZZZ
                </a>
            </li>
            <li class="hide-on-toggle">
                <a href="https://login.html?serviceIier" target="_blank">
                  <span class="fa-stack fa-lg">
                    <i class="fa fa-desack-1x "></i>
                  </span> joozz
                </a>
            </li>
           
          </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
```

So here is my code so far

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("https://Login")


username = driver.find_element_by_id("username")
username.clear()
username.send_keys("etggrgrw.")

password = driver.find_element_by_name("password")
password.clear()
password.send_keys("xxxx")


driver.find_element_by_name("login").click()

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[text()='JIZZZ']").click();
```

I get an error of :

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='JIZZZ']"}
```

I also tried

```
driver.find_element_by_XPath("//*[@id=menu]/li[9]/a").Click()
```

but got error of :

```
AttributeError: 'WebDriver' object has no attribute 'find_element_by_XPath'
```

I am lost and appreciate any help.

Comment: change `JIZZZ` to `/JIZZZ`?

Answer (score 0):

`driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'JIZZZ')]").click()`

Comment: It is not giving me any error but it is not opening the new page either. what if I wanted to go with '''<li class="hide-on-toggle jizzzHidden">
                <a href="/JIZZZ" target="_blank">'''  so the driver finds the link in the <a herf ?

Comment: Oops. Meant `find_element` not `elements`. To actually click on the element, it would be: `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'JIZZZ')]").click()`

Comment: Didn't work. got below error: '''selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(text(), 'JIZZZ')]"}''' . maybe because the text of span is not clickable. but the link inside the <a herf is clickable. I just don't know how select the a herf element.

Comment: I got it. I had to go with the full Xpath "driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div[1]/div/ul/li[9]/a").click()". Thanks for the help anyways